# drawing a horizontal line using <hr/> html

Tags: html, css

I want to draw a horizontal line after every rows of my data

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
          data a
        </td>
    </tr>
    <hr/>
    <tr>
        <td>
          data b
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

but my output for my codes is like this

```
 __________________________________________________________
 data a
 data b
```

expect results

```
 data a
 __________________________________________________________
 data b
```

---

additional question

if let's say I have a few tables rows but some rows doesn't requires the horizontal line can I do something like

```
 .styletr {border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
```

and then

```
  <tr class=styletr>
  </tr>
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using an <hr> tag with a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522337/using-an-hr-tag-with-a-table)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can use hr inside a table, you are better off using css:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="YourCss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

and inside "YourCss.css":

```
tr { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
```

EDIT: This will, however, put a border at the bottom of every table row, including the last row, to exclude the last row you will need something like

```
tr:not(:last-child) { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
```

EDIT 2: For greater control over which rows are styled, you should use a class:

```
<tr class="seperator">...</tr>

.seperator { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
```

Comment: if let's say I have a few tables rows but some rows doesn't requires the horizontal line can I do something like .styletr {border-bottom: 1px solid black;} and then <tr class=styletr>?

Comment: Spot on, add a class to the <tr>s that you want to style, then use that class in the css.

Answer (score 6):

The most common method is to use CSS to set the `border` property of your element, as such:

```
tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

In the case of your code, the `hr` element would not make sense to use.

Answer (score 5):

`<hr />` is no longer used as a physical separator between two html sections in HTML5 (see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp)). Instead it is now a logical separation. You could use `border` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot place elements between tr tags of a table. The browser will simply relocate it to outside of the table when rendering.
One option would be to put it in it's own row with a single cell spanning the width of the table

```
<tr><td><hr /></td></tr>
```

(If you have more columns use colspan like so)

```
<tr><td colspan="3"><hr /></td></tr>
```

Alternately, if you really only have one column in your table, just move the HR tag into the  tag so it's inside the cell.

You could also consider (and I encourage you to) replace the HR tag with bottom borders on the table rows, as other answers have suggested, as that is a much better design approach.

Answer (score 2):

It's not valid `<html>` to put anything except `<tr>`, `<thead>` or `<tbody>` as a direct child of a `<table>` element.

Instead, perhaps try adding `css`:

```
tr { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
```

Comment: @BalvantAhir different email engines support different html/css/... and have their own quirks. Its been a while since I wrote markup for emails, but it might work to *inline* this CSS on the <tr> element. That is: `<tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">...`

Comment: when i use : <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">  its not work... but <tr><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></td></tr> works....

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    <td>
      <hr />
    </td>
```

if it's an email content